# ¿Como crear un Banner con StartApp?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que necesito poder mostrar un banner y estoy usando el sdk de StartApp. Y no se muestra el banner no solo eso me da el muy conocido error se ha cerrado la aplicacion.

Mi código de layout:

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
 android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Y mi código del onCreate() de la Activity es:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     StartAppSDK.init(this, "202753996", true);
     StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState);
     Banner banner = (com.startapp.android.publish.ads.banner.Banner) findViewById(R.id.startAppBanner); 
        banner.showBanner();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_de);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



}
```

Si conocen como solucionar mi problema. Por favor comunicármelo Gracias

Mi logcat

```
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.virtualdisk/com.example.virtualdisk.DE}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at com.example.virtualdisk.DE.onCreate(DE.java:60)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
03-30 08:19:49.677: E/AndroidRuntime(8111):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Añade la traza del error, asi sera mas facil saber porque te sucede esto.

Comment: Ya las añado Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes vincular el layout

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.[nombre del layout]);
```

Comment: El layout ya esta vinculado y esta debajo de `banner.showBanner()`. Gracias

Comment: debería estar arriba del banner

Comment: Pero la documentación de StartApp no dice que se debe colocar antes  del `setContentView(R.layout.activity_de);`. Gracias

Comment: de echo si lo dice https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/StartApp_InApp_SDK_Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/startapp/startappinterstitialexample/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Debes vincular primero tu layout y despues el banner

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_de);
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
     StartAppSDK.init(this, "202753996", true);
     StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState);
     Banner banner = (com.startapp.android.publish.ads.banner.Banner)findViewById(R.id.startAppBanner);

     banner.showBanner();
}
```

Comment: Pero la documentación de StartApp no dice que se debe colocar antes  del `setContentView(R.layout.activity_de);`. Gracias

Comment: Si pero recuerda que en tu codigo estas tratando de mostras tu banner sin que aun este vinculada el layoutprimero, por lo cual al tratar de obtener el banner de dara un nullo,intenta hacer lo que te explique no pierdes nada

Comment: Ok lo intentare, te tendré informado si ocurre un cambio. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar mi error colocando el código de ejemplo que se encuentra en github: https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/StartApp_InApp_SDK_Example

Comment: en el mismo ejemplo sale que inicializa antes el layout... https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/StartApp_InApp_SDK_Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/startapp/startappinterstitialexample/MainActivity.java
me alegro que lo allas solucionado

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo